# Bootstrap: Firefox is breaking my page layout

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I just built a homepage utilizing images mainly as the site is a photography site; however, I checked the site in Chrome and Safari and works perfectly, but FIREFOX is another issue.

It seems as if Firefox is breaking my layout when resizing the browser, mainly with the image resizing.  It seems as if I have checked every area for a solution and can't figure it out...

Can anyone help???

My site is: [www.theartxp.com/roze](http://www.theartxp.com/roze)

Comment: You have an issue, you're importing bootstrap css inside `custom.css` but you are also linking the files inside `<head>` use one or the other

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is that the image container is set to `display:inline-block` which means it should span the whole size of its children, but since you're trying to limit the width of the image based on the parent's size (`max-width:100%`) they kind of cancel each other out. The width of the container will always be the width of the image.

You should let the container div display as block:

```
.he-wrap {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
    /*display: inline-block; remove this*/
    /*position: relative; remove this too since it's a duplicate*/
}
```

Answer (score -2):

<strike>The w3.org spec states that max-width does not apply to inline elements</strike>. It looks like it does apply to replaced elements. My mistake. Anyways,  To fix your issue, change your image width to `width: 100%` instead of `max-width: 100%` and it works just fine.

*Meta:* As a side note, when someone provides a good fix, but not 100% accurate information, there is an edit button for that. Mass down-voting simply just discourages contributions without making StackOverflow any better.

Comment: `max-width` does apply to images, the specification reads: `Applies to: All elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups` and `<img>` is a replaced element since it loads content from an external source.

Comment: The first solution worked, but I will try this and see what happens. Thank you!